# nginx run npm with non-default port?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have my angular app running in the root url, port 80, and I want to access the api running at port 8090. But when I try to change the port nginx listens to 8090 it says that I have a conflict (since npm is running it at 8090). So I switched it to 8100 instead. But when I try to hit that port it doesn't connect. My goal is to be able to go to http://174.131.183.112:8100 for my api.

```
server {
    listen 8100;
    server_name api._;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://174.131.183.112:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Note: the weird thing is that if I don't have anything else running in nginx, then it still uses default port 80 to connect to my api, as if the 8100 wasn't there at all.

Comment: oh yeah - I'm running this on DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I setup ufw to block all ports. So I had to sudo ufw allow 8100 to open it and now it works.